# Why is Interface Builder showing Portrait view for "w Any h Compact"?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, size-classes

I'm trying to create an app where the layout changes if you rotate it. I'm trying to do this with Auto Layout and size classes. My problem it that this project somehow keeps the view in Portrait, even though I have selected the size class "w Any h Compact". In another project "w Any h Compact" shows up as landscape in IB. Both projects are set for 8.1 iPhone. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! Somebody else in my team had set the Simulated Metrics Size to iPhone. Setting it to Inferred solved my problem.

[image]